# User can use only their category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I need find some solution how to allow category edit or use for post only for user which create this category. So I need assign author for taxonomy. It is possible to do this? I know that with posts it is possible to allow users to see their post.

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom new add-post form. In this form, with if clause filter your taxs.